# Help with Xcode drawRect using textfield to input value

Tags: xcode, nsstring, int, textfield, drawrect

i am currently trying to do a bar graph in XCode. I have tried CPGraph and all the stuff around but they are all out of date and i need help for XCode 4. I am completely newb with this and that's why i need your help.

Here is my code:

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect

{

```
NSString *s = textField.text;
value = [s intValue];
NSLog(@"%i",value);


    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 60);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGFloat components[] = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0};

    CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(colorspace, components);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 400, value);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 400, 100);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
    CGColorRelease(color);
```

}

Notice that i have changed one of the point value for "value".
What i have done is create a UITextField and i want to be able to write like 500 in the UITextField and that the bar adjust itself. Currently the NSLog tell me that value is equal to 0 even if, before building my app i manually enter a number in the TextField.
I have been searching fo 3 days now and everything i found give me errors and are incomplete as i says i know almost nothing about objective-c in xcode. I also noticed during my search that this type of line doesn't refresh real time if you dont tell him. I would like help with that too if that's part of my problem. If you want more information on my code just tell me.
I will be really grateful if somebody can help me.

here is my .h :

@interface draw2D : UIView

{

```
 UITextField *textField;
```

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

@end

Comment: I'm assuming that you have connected the text field to an IBOutlet in Interface builder?

Comment: here is what i did :


@interface draw2D : UIView 
{
     
UITextField *textField;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

@end

Comment: Typically if you are using interface builder (IB) to bind your text field (or anything for that matter) via an IBOutlet, you do not need to add it as a property.  So I'm assuming you used IB to connect the text field to your instance you have declared above right?  Without doing that your text field will be nil.

Comment: instance? the only thing that is linked to my textField is under referencing outlets and its file's owner. as i said i dont really understand what im doing

Comment: OK, then yea, you have that right it sounds like.  Don't know, the code looks right (though I have not run it), I would suggest printing out the string in the text field: NSLog(@"%@", s); and see if that is what you think it is.  Also, I do not see a declaration for "value".  Make sure it is: int value = [s intValue];  I'm out for the day so I'll check in on this tomorrow.

Comment: Good idea on trying to nslog s value it gives me (null) so that mean that he doesnt get what im entering in my textfield right? and for value i created i had an int value in my other .h but ive just removed it and put it as you said so now it looks like :int value = [s intValue];. i still don't get why i cant retreive the value of my textfield tho. thx for the help btw

Comment: i think this line : NSString *s = textField.text; may be wrong ive been searching around a lot on how to retrieve a textfield and put it into an int variable but its the only one that did not create an error so i sticked with it but i dont know if its good or not.

Comment: Well here is how I would do it:

NSString* txt = [textField text]; // Alternate to textField.text
int i = [txt intValue];
NSLog(@"i == %d", i);

Provided your outlet is hooked up right, that should give you what you want.  You can check that by doing an NSLog on your text field too... (sorry about the formatting...)

Comment: Wait a minute...  this class that has your IBOutlet, is that your app delegate?  Probably not since that is a UIView.  So...  let me put in the answer below

Answer (score 0):

OK, it looks like since you have your text field hooked up in IB to File's Owner, that is typically your app delegate which is not the class you have above as that is a UIView.  So, not unless you changed File's Owner to this UIView then your text field is not hooked up.  So, typically what I do is to add a UIView to the xib window in IB (if you are not using the one that comes free when you create a XIB).  Then that is what I'll attach the text box to, not File's Owner.  Kind of begs the question of how anything is attached to Files Owner not unless you have a UITextField declared in there too (again providing you didn't change the class from the app delegate to this view class).

I know that if someone is new to this is is almost like greek.  I developed in Java, C/C++, C#, etc for years and this was like learning how to program all over again.

If you are new to this I highly suggest the iPhone dev book by Big Nerd Ranch.  I found it very useful.

Comment: That was exactly it thank you very much. Now i was wondering if i want to change the value of textField realtime and the bar update itself. is it doable and if it is how can i do that. i was thinking inserting a refresh button but i don't know the command to refresh a view and how to link it. any idea? btw thanks again.

Comment: Well what you could do is setup your view or view controller as a UITextFieldDelegate (implement that protocol).  Then you would override the - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField method in your .m file.  Get the text from the text field then make a call to [self setNeedsDisplay] (where self is the view.  If you did that in the view controller it would be [[self view] setNeedsDisplay]).  Lastly you would use IB to set the delegate of the text field to the view or view controller (which ever you chose for the UITextFieldDelegate).

Comment: Again, I highly suggest getting a book to go over this and work the examples.  It take a little time but is well worth it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found out how to redraw my line with a button refresh.

What I did was create a button and link it with my UIView where my line is being drawn. Inside I wrote `[self setNeedsDisplay];` and each time I click the button it refreshes the view and gives me back my NSlog that I set in the same method as my drawRect.

Many thanks again Merky.